# Windows 10 File Property of a PowerPoint 365 document : How to recover missing author?

Tags: windows-10, file-management, tracking, authoring, windows-audit-mode

Author is blank (File Explorer view) in File Property of a PowerPoint 365 document.

Is it possible to recover missing author ?

Auditing is not enabled in said Document.

Thanks Ahead!

Comment: How exactly was this field cleared in the first place? Even if you were tracking changes to the document, that particular feature, wouldn’t have been tracking changes to the author field.

Comment: author is missing in both File Explorer view and File > Info.
so far this case applies to file from others (stored locally and cloud storage) even after my modication; this behaviour make it challenging to detect modification and by whom.
 "By default, the author of a document is set to the username we entered to sign-in to Office. " My default is not enabled but author is shown in a PowerPoint I created; however, why is it not shown when I modified a PowerPoint document from eMail attachment?